# Disjunctive Normal Form

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

The boolean expression:

y= (a'+b) * (b(c'+d')) = (a'+b) * (bc' + bd')

is given.

Find out the disjunctive normal form to this boolean expression.

My suggestion:

y= a'bc'd' + a'bc'd + a'bcd' + abc'd' + abc'd+abcd'

only when these terms are true the function is 1 and otherwise not. (=0)

Is the DNF right?

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Here ist the truth table for the boolean expression:

[image]

Comment: You might notice that a has no effect on the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks good your original equation reduces to (bc' + bd') which is what you have put in your truth table and then extracted in DNF.

Edit to clarify reduction of original equation.

(a'+b) * (bc' + bd')= a'(bc' + bd')+b(bc' + bd')

```
              = a'(bc' + bd')+(bc' + bd')

              = (bc' + bd')
```

Comment: the simplified boolean equation would be b(c'+d'), so i could simplify the DNF to y= bc'd' + bc'd + bcd' + bc'd' + bc'd+bcd' , right?

Comment: @lightsodium DNF requires all the variables to be present in all of the terms.

Comment: oh,thanks! so it still would be y= a'bc'd' + a'bc'd + a'bcd' + abc'd' + abc'd+abcd'

Comment: "that looks good your original equation reduces to (bc' + bd')": how can I read this just out of the truth table? and not by using laws to reduce the equation

Comment: You can't you have to use the laws of boolean algebra to get to (bc' + bd'). After you put this in your truth table you can read out the DNF form.

Comment: but i have not to simplify it to read out the DNF form? I could just work with the original equation?

Comment: Yes you could, whichever you find easier.